# Memory Allocation and Mir

Tags: d, mir

I'm trying to work in an environment in which I need to minimize dynamic allocations and I was curious as to how the sliced function works in terms of memory allocation. I've looked around and haven't found much.

Is it possible to have slices allocated on the stack if they are constant size?

Comment: Silces are never allocated per se, they just point to existing memory. You can slice stuff on the stack. Only caveat is when you append to a slice then it creates a new memory block. So the answer depends on your context.... what do you plan to slice? What will you be doing with it?

Comment: I'm using constant size slices for linear algebra. So like if I wanted to do a linear transformation A * x and A is known to be 3x3 at compile time and x is known to be 3x1 at compile time.

Was hoping to see if I could do some deterministic programming by shutting off the GC and using as much stack allocation as possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
import std; 
@nogc void main()
{          
    import mir.ndslice;
    import mir.ndslice.topology; 
    import mir.blas : gemv, gemm;

    scope double[9] aData = 0;
    scope double[3] vData = [1, 2, 1]; 
    scope double[3] cData;

    auto A = aData.sliced.sliced(3, 3);
    auto v = vData.sliced.sliced(3, 1);
    auto c = cData.sliced.sliced(3, 1);

    A.diagonal[0] = 2;
    A.diagonal[1] = 1;
    A.diagonal[2] = 0;

    // c = 1 * A * v + 0 * c
    gemm!double(1, A, v, 0, c);

}
```

Experimented around for quite a bit and got this as my zero GC (minus writeln of course) linear algebra. Looks pretty clunky and I was hoping for something nicer like in slice.

Again recently found out about D and was trying to see if it had any chance doing this stuff deterministically for some robotics projects when linear algebra algorithms are necessary.

Probably shouldn't be using gemm but didn't feel like digging up gemv. Not as elegant as something like `slice!double(3, 3)`

Adam said something about slices never being allocated but I'm still wary about letting the GC loose at all.

I work typically with a lot of DC motors doing kinematic simulations. Millisecond level timing is critical and D proposed it could be like that so I checked it out because C++ is painful to work with.

Though I have to ask why this doesn't work.

```
    double[9] a_data;
    scope A = a_data.sliced(3, 3);
```

when this does...

```
    auto a_data = new double[9]; // Gah new?!
    scope A = a_data.sliced(3, 3);
```

While the 2nd is far more elegant.

Comment: oh you probably just need to do `a_data[].sliced(3,3)`! I've been so busy this week which is why I haven't done a full type up yet, but the short version is the slice operator - that `[]` thing - transforms any block of memory into a dynamic slice.  Many functions expect dynamic slices but don't care what they actually point to. Just when it sees `double[9]` it thinks that is a by-value block to copy... but `double[]` is a by-reference (sort of) block to point to. `a_data[]` slices without copying.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there's a way to bundle the array with the data for an instantiation as simple as `slice!double(3, 3)`. But either way thanks for your time. What you said worked. Looking forward to that writeup.